# Using AdvancedFilter to find Uniques across Sheets VBA

Tags: excel, vba, advanced-filter

Im trying to extract the unique names of companies across 6 different sheets, and compile them into one column for later use in a matrix. Each company name list is in column G of each sheet.

So far I've generated a macro in VBA to extract the unique names for one column of one sheet, but now Im trying to format the sheets into an Array, ie: Array = (Sheet1,Sheet2,Sheet3...) and have the advanced filter run on column G for each sheet in the array. Below is the code for the single column unique values:

```
Sub AdvFilter() ' ' AdvFilter Macro

    ' Select first cell in column (Sheet1!A2)
    Range("Central!A2").Select

    ' Extending the selection down to the cell just above the first blank cell in this column
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    ' Execute Advanced Filter on selection and copy to Sheet1!C2
    Selection.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Range( _
     "Central!C2"), Unique:=True


End Sub
```

Any help for the additions to this code to have it run on each sheet is appreciated

Comment: You can refer to this answer to copy the all the data into  separate sheet

Answer (score 0):

**Use this:**

```
Sub AdvFilter() ' ' AdvFilter Macro

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        sht.Range("G2:G" & Range("G2").End(xlDown).row).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=sht.Range("H2"), Unique:=True

    Next

End Sub
```

This macro will apply filter on G column of each sheet and copy the Unique values in H column of each sheet.

**You can change the `CopyToRange:=sht.Range("H2")` line to paste in an individual or specific sheet instead of each sheet.**